# Narrow by search price in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

On left navigation bar ,in "shop By price" functionality the price is displayed twice. Could anyone help me by letting me know why it is displayed twice. Any kind of solution will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check your XML files.  Chances are you have two of the following lines:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

A tip to help you find it:  Look in `/app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/layout/catalog.xml`  (where `YourTheme` is your custom theme).  Search for "layer_view" in the file.

You should only have one in the `Category layered navigation layout` section that starts with `<catalog_category_layered translate="label">`.